AVERAGEIFS on multiple worksheets
I am fairly new to vba and trying to apply a formula that can do an average with 2 conditions on multiple worksheets.
It needs to be a formula and not a calcul as the data searched might change and the script must run only once.
The data itself is inside of column S in the sheets and the first condition is whether or not the number is superior to a set integer (found on the homepage of the Excel in F10)
The second condition is to check the group in which the data is from, it will always be a string and the range is found in column A the condition itself is inside a cell two columns before (see screenshot)
Screenshot of the formating
To resolve this problem I used a list of all worksheets of interest (in column 9 or I and row from 3)
And then I used INDIRECT as the adress for my AVERAGEIFS.
It made this formula
nb_ws = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Results").Columns("I:I"))
Worksheets("Results").Cells(11, 23).Formula2R1C1 = "=AVERAGEIFS(INDIRECT(""'""&R3C9:R" & nb_ws + 2 & "C9&""'!""&""S:S""),""'""&R3C9:R" & nb_ws + 2 & "C9&""'!""&""S:S"","">=""&'Homepage'!R10C6,INDIRECT(""'""&R3C9:R" & nb_ws + 2 & "C9&""'!""&""A:A""),RC[-3])"

As of now it doesn't work and I really wonder if using a "for each" and making averages per sheets and only then making a general average would be better, I was advised by a coworker with more experience to avoid "for each" but it seems much simpler. We are allowed to modify all the sheets but shouldn't touch the data itself.
Could you please confirm if I am on the right track or should I change my method ?
I am not looking for a solution but more of a method as I would like to truly understand what I do and how it works.
Thank you.

The AVERAGEIFS function cannot be used in this way:
=AVERAGEIFS(Sheet1:Sheet7!$S:$S,Sheet1:Sheet7!$S:$S,
"<="&'Homepage'!$F$10,Sheet1:Sheet7!$A:$A,Results!T11)

Its range arguments must be single-sheet references. Only selected functions accept 3D references (to several adjacent sheets). In the past these were mainly functions such as SUM, recently functions such as VSTACK or TOCOL have been added. This can be used in this case. But the ranges in individual sheets cannot include entire columns, because you cannot exceed the limit of about 10^6 rows in total.
Besides, such calculations take longer. Limit the range to as many rows as you actually need.
You can use for example:
=AVERAGE(FILTER(VSTACK(Sheet1:Sheet7!$S$1:$S$1000),
(VSTACK(Sheet1:Sheet7!$S$1:$S$1000)<=Homepage!$F$10)*
(VSTACK(Sheet1:Sheet7!$A$1:$A$1000)=Results!T11)))

Or
=AVERAGE(FILTER(TOCOL(Sheet1:Sheet7!$S$1:$S$1000),
(TOCOL(Sheet1:Sheet7!$S$1:$S$1000)<=Homepage!$F$10)
*(TOCOL(Sheet1:Sheet7!$A$1:$A$1000)=Results!T11)))


Oh okay thank you, I used a similar formula with SUM and wondered why this one didn't work.
Seems strange that thos two are trated differently.
Also big thank you for the tips about full column, I changed the whole program to fit your advice and gained a lot of execution time.

If you used the formula I gave in the answer above, it should work with both functions SUM and AVERAGE. You can try to omit the AVERAGE function and then you will get the result in the form of an array. You can apply both SUM and AVERAGE to this array.

So, this might be an option you could look at:

I do this with a sheet called "first sheet" and "last sheet" so that any sheets between those are included while those outside are not. This method may address your issue of updating when the range changes etc.
Sheet 1 has the value 1 in cell A1, sheet 2 has 2 etc which means the total of 1+2+3+4+5 = 15.

First, thank you it seems much simpler however I tried your method but I always have a #value! error.
The formula I used is "=AVERAGEIFS(Sheet1:Sheet7!$S:$S,Sheet1:Sheet7!$S:$S,"<="&'Homepage'!$F$10,Sheet1:Sheet7!$A:$A,Results!T11)"
